# Python, Kivy. Limit input values between two numbers with a TextInput filter

Tags: python, kivy

I need a `TextInput filter` with a `minimum (1)` and a `maximum (100)` value. The filter should allow `integer only` + I want to `avoid: 'ValueError`: could not convert string to float or int:'.

**So my goal is:** TextInput let numbers between 1-100 only.

I tried a few solutions like simple if-else code but it wasn't elegant, simple enough  and top of that my code become a little bit messy too.

This is why I thought I need a TextInput filter. I know there are samples on the offical site and I tried to create a filter but it seems my knowledge is not enough for that (yet).

Could you help me to solve this?

*I've created a simple example:*

My file `.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class NewTextInput(TextInput):
    input_filter = ObjectProperty('int', allownone=True)

    max_characters = 2
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if len(self.text) > self.max_characters and self.max_characters > 0:
            substring = ""
        TextInput.insert_text(self, substring, from_undo)

    #This is where I need the filter.
    #min_value = 1
    #max_value = 100
    #def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
       #...

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

My file `.kv`

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: "Sample"
    NewTextInput:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_filter = 'int'

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if substring in string.digits:
            cc, cr = self.cursor
            text = self._lines[cr]
            new_text = text[:cc] + substring + text[cc:]
            if int(new_text) > 100:
                return
        super(MyTextInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need!